# How to pass properties to tomcat through command line

Tags: tomcat

I need to pass -Dlog4j.debug  to tomcat through command line, how to do that ??
The platform in Linux box, the command is
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

I've tried set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.debug=true but noway !!

The solution is :

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.debug=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're starting tomcat, but doing:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.debug=true
```

And then starting it on the same command line, will do the job.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

For permanent solution you can set it in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dlog4j.debug=true"
```

then run tomcat from any command-line `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`

Comment: Don't you need to add 'export' before CATALINA_OPTS ?